# pig script failing with GC:Overhead limit exceeded

Tags: out-of-memory, apache-pig, heap-size

I am running one pig script on around 1 gb of data which involves several groupby and foreach statement.
here is sample pig code:

> ab =   GROUP y   BY(y1,
>       y2,
>       y3,
>       y4,
>       y5,
>       y6   ) ;
>
> xy =   FOREACH ab { 
>       abc = FOREACH y 
>         GENERATE 
>          x1,
>          x2,
>          x3,
>          x4,
>          x5,
>          x6,
>          rel1,
>          rel2; 
>   GENERATE 
>   group, abc;
>   } ;

Note: **rel1 and rel2** are  genereted by group by they are also bag in itself and for one [y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6] the bagsize contains around 448 records which is of size 700mb and pig is failing for xy relation saying GC Overhead limit exceeded .

**Yarn Logs**

```
2018-08-08 15:01:13,299 INFO [Service Thread] org.apache.pig.impl.util.SpillableMemoryManager: first memory handler call - Collection threshold init = 1148190720(1121280K) used = 5726479864(5592265K) committed = 5726797824(5592576K) max = 5726797824(5592576K), toFree = 3046581752
2018-08-08 15:04:22,192 FATAL [ResponseProcessor for block BP-1779694772-10.xxx.xx.17-1533341581987:blk_1074055963_315162] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.YarnUncaughtExceptionHandler: Thread Thread[ResponseProcessor for block BP-1779694772-10.xxx.xx.17-1533341581987:blk_1074055963_315162,5,main] threw an Error.  Shutting down now...
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
2018-08-08 15:05:24,112 INFO [ResponseProcessor for block BP-1779694772-10.xxx.xx.17-1533341581987:blk_1074055963_315162] org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Halt with status -1 Message: HaltException
```

Comment: put the exact log as well.